# A row is missing from one of my tables in my Django site. Where did it go?

Tags: django, postgresql

A row is missing from one of my tables in my Django site.

1. There is absolutely nothing in django_admin_log table mentioning that it was deleted. There were other deletions performed on that day and they were saved. Also, I checked Django's admin code and it looks like it tries logging the deletion first, so even if the deletion was made in a non-transaction manner, in the worst case I'd have log entry and a non-deleted record.
2. There are no logs in the web log, neither nginx nor my web app log, that suggest that it was removed by Django-admin. There are logs of another deletion made on that day, so I guess deletions were logged.
3. The database in question is PostgreSQL. I've just read about `pg_dirtyread`, unfortunately, I've just vacuumed the database a moment ago.

My takes:

1. Delete query typed from command-line utility - nope, nobody was logged-in on that day.
2. Hacker? Come on, why would a hacker delete a single record from a table of a custom CMS-like software?
3. Hardware fault? Memory problems would manifest in other, random ways. Disk problems - probably too. I have found an anecdotal mention of a record missing from an index in PostgreSQL because of overheating CPU, which would also give other issues, I guess. This is too narrow issue to be causes by hardware faults, I think. On the other hand, the record was "cleanly" dropped, taking some other records with it, as per CASCADE rules in the database.

Do you have any ideas on how that single row could be gone missing?

Any suggestions on how do I prevent such issues from happening again? Log all DELETE queries in PostgreSQL? Or just all queries? Log all shell commands/access? Log everything?

Comment: Can you share the view where you render the rows?

Comment: Admin view? Sure: https://github.com/iplweb/bpp/blob/dev/src/bpp/admin/autor.py#L140